# How can I flip a vector such as 1:10 to 10:1 in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, math

Suppose I have `'1 2 3'`. I want to get `'3 2 1'`. How can I get it in Matlab?

**More verbose example**

```
N=64;
[x y]=meshgrid(linspace(-3*pi,3*pi,N),linspace(-3*pi,3*pi,N));
t=sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);

% Now instead of "f=t+2*sinc(t);", I want to get all elements inverted aka 
% first element becomes the last and so on -- I thought it would be 
% sinc(abs(length(t)-t)) but it is not.
```

Comment: I suspect you meant `[1 2 3]` rather than `'1 2 3'` as your starting point - but as it happens, the solution below works just as well for either.

Comment: In the example of your question, both `sinc` and `f` are symmetric functions, i.e.`sinc(-x)=sinc(x)`, where `x` is some positive number etc, hence flipping the vector via  `fliplr` won't change the outcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the MATLAB function [`fliplr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html).

Comment: It's worth noting that it would work only on row vectors. A column vector would've required [`flipud`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html) instead. Also, a more general approach is `x(end:-1:1)`.